# Get key/value in an object inside an array based on knowing other key values boto3

Tags: python, json, boto3

```
"clone": [
        {
            "href": "http://abc.compute.amazonaws.com:7990/scm/fin/test.git",
            "name": "http",
        },
        {
            "href": "ssh://git@abc.compute.amazonaws.com:7999/fin/test.git",
            "name": "ssh",
        },
    ]
```

I have an array with two objects which shifts randomly, how can I extract **href** value inside the first object based on referring to **name**(which remains static) using python boto3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do linear search:

```
href = next(x for x in array if x['name']=='ssh')['href']
```

this will throw exception if your `array` has no such dict/object with the matching `name`.